# Положить в HashMap одинаково параметризованные дженерики

Tags: java, generics

Предположим, есть следующая иерархия классов:

```
static interface A
{
    void roll();
}

static class B implements A
{
    @Override
    public void roll() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

static class C implements A
{
    @Override
    public void roll() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

Требуется положить в `HashMap` следующее: `map.put(Class<E>, List<E>)`, где `E` - класс, наследующийся от A, причем, нужно запретить класть разноименно параметризованные классы. Пример:
Должно компилироваться:

```
map.put(Class<B>,List<B>);
map.put(Class<C>,List<C>);
```

Ошибка компиляции:

```
map.put(Class<B>, List<C>);
```

Как это можно реализовать, если вообще такое возможно?

Comment: Что если сделать кастомную мапу `class CustomMap<T> extends HashMap<Class<T>, List<T>> { }` и уже её использовать?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, если задать параметр A, то ничего кроме Class<A> и List<A> класть не будет, при попытке положить Class<B>, List<B> выдает ошибку

Comment: тогда реализуйте свой метод `put` как-то так: `<T extends A> void put(Class<T> k, List<T> v)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно сделать так:

```
private static <E extends A> Map<Class<E>, List<E>> getMap() {
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

И использовать этот метод следующим образом:

```
Map<Class<B>, List<B>> map = getMap();
map.put(B.class, new ArrayList<>());
map.put(C.class, new ArrayList<>()); //<- ошибка компиляции
```

**UPDATE**:

Боюсь, то что вы хотите, нельзя сделать без создания дополнительного класса, который реализовывал бы данное ограничение.

Например так:

```
private static class CustomMap<T> {
    private final Map<Class<? extends T>, List<? extends T>> map = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <P extends T> List<P> get(P key) {
        return (List<P>) map.get(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <P extends T> List<P> put(Class<P> key, List<P> value) {
        return (List<P>) map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Тогда,

```
CustomMap<A>map = new CustomMap<>() ;

map.put(C.class, new ArrayList<C>());
map.put(B.class, new ArrayList<B>());
map.put(C.class, new ArrayList<B>()); //<-- ошибка компиляции
```

Но в данном решении есть существенные недостатки, одно из них это то, что `CustomMap` не реализовывает интерфейс `Map`

Comment: Немного не то. Сделал поправку в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя сделать так?

```
class CustomMap<T> extends HashMap<Class<? extends T>, List<? extends T>> {
}
```

Тогда можно писать например так:

```
CustomMap<B> customMap=new CustomMap<B>();
//работает
customMap.put(B.class, listB);
//а так уже выдаст ошибку
customMap.put(С.class, new ArrayList<B>());
//так тоже ошибка компиляции
customMap.put(B.class, new ArrayList<C>());
```

Ну и не нужно фокусов с оберткой и проч. пассов

Comment: В таком случае я не смогу выполнить customMap.put(C.class, new ArrayList<C>());

Comment: Конечно, но если вы сделаете `CustomMap<C> customC=new CustomMap<C>()` - то сможете

Comment: Но мне нужно хранить оба этих значения